# SBT multi-project build : 2 different versions of sbt play plugin for different subprojects

Tags: scala, playframework, ant, sbt, ivy

I have an `sbt` project containing 2 play sub-projects with 2 different versions of play (and basically 2 different versions of Scala: 2.12 and 2.10). Is there a way to use two versions of the play plugin?
This is my `plugins.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

resolvers += "Akka Snapshot Repository" at "https://repo.akka.io/snapshots/"
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.7") 
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.7")
```

And this is `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val global = Project("root",file("."))

lazy val play28 = Project( "play_2.8_subproject" , file("subs/ply28/")).settings(
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq( jdbc , ehcache , ws , specs2 % Test , guice ),
  scalaVersion := "2.12.2"
).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

lazy val play23 = Project( "play_2.3_subproject" , file("subs/pl23/")).settings(
  scalaVersion := "2.10.5",
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq( jdbc  , ws  )  
).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

I can run the play 2.8 subproject. Nevertheless, play plugin 2.8 is still not resolved with Scala 2.10 when trying to run the play 2.3 project.

> (play_2.3_subproject/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency:
> com.typesafe.play#play-server_2.10;2.8.7: not found

You get the idea, I want to switch between the two play projects and enable the appropriate plugin version for each subproject.

Is that possible in the first place ? If yes how can I achieve the desired behaviour ?
Note I am using sbt 0.13.

Comment: I think that asking such questions is a great sign to stop using Scala 2.10, and upgrade to latest sbt.

Comment: @Tomer Shetah , I want to keep using both versions 2.10 and 2.12 depending on the subproject

Comment: I don't have hard evidence, but I am pretty sure this is not possible. And even if it was, there are breaking changes between those versions. How do you plan to write code that is good for both? See here for example: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Migration26 . What are you trying to achieve? Why using both versions?

Comment: @Tomer Shetah , I have already the play 2.3 subproject working , I want to add a new play 2.8 subproject without touching to the old play subproject. At first sight I thought there will be no problem since every subproject has its own settings; until I got stuck with the plugin stuff, I can't have two different versions of the play plugin inside plugins.sbt . If I try to run the old play project (2.3) , sbt tries to retrieve to play 2.8 plugin with scala 2.10 which results in an unresolved dependency exception.

Comment: Yeap, as I said, I don't think it is possible. But if you are using git, it saves your history, therefore you don't need to have both, you can safely upgrade to latests and use only those.

Comment: @Tomer Shetah, if I got you right then I need to disable the play plugin for the old subproject and use only the new one with play 2.8 , ( by the way we wanted to create a new separate subproject because we couldn't upgrade for 2.3 to 2.8 in the first place). So the goal was to keep both projects untill we get the new one working and then delete the old one.
Also , does the scalaVersion in the root project matter in this case ? And also does the plugins.sbt get loaded whenever a subproject is ran ? can't we have 2 different files and load them conditionally depending on the subproject ?

Comment: Helix I am not aware of such option, and I am pretty sure there is no such. In general, it is a bad practice to have 2 source codes that are doing the same, for migration. You need to put down the effort of migrating, and then you'll enjoy the latest updates performance and features. The `scalaVersion` does matter. You can run `sbt scalaVersion` to see the project version (I'd guess it is 2.12.X)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up the discussion from the comments, it is probably impossible. One of the difficulties for example is to enable `PlayScala` in `build.sbt`. As described in [The `/build.sbt` file (version 2.8)](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/BuildOverview#The-/build.sbt-file.) or at [Auto Plugins and plugin settings (version 2.3)](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23#Auto-Plugins-and-plugin-settings), in both versions you enable the plugin:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

when `PlayScala` is defined at `play.sbt.PlayScala` in both versions.

Having that said, even if it would be possible to build such a structure, it will be really hard to maintain, as there are breaking changes between Play 2.3 and Play 2.8, as elaborated in:

- [Play 2.4 Migration Guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Migration24)
- [Play 2.5 Migration Guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Migration25)
- [Play 2.6 Migration Guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Migration26)
- [Play 2.7 Migration Guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Migration27)
- [Play 2.8 Migration Guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Migration28)

The best approach that should be taken in order to upgrade the Play version, is do it in one shot. Upgrade Scala, Play, and sbt all at once to latests. It will probably take less time then figuring out how to have both Play versions in the same project.

For future maintenance, the best will be to upgrade once a new version is out there. This way you don't have to do much changes to keep it up. Furthermore, you get the latest updates which usually includes security vulnerabilities fixes, performance improvements, and bug fixes, along with new features.